# Core Data Limitations and when not to save data persistently

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm building a social app with features including feed, profile, friends and followers. I'm using core-data to save all the objects persistently. When a user launches the app the data is fetched from core-data and displayed to the user instantly, but I'm also fetching updates in the background.

The problem is that currently I'm saving everything in core-data. For instance, if I visit a friends profile, I fetch the friend's feed objects and save those in core-data too. Now the next time I visit the same friend's profile, I just show the saved feed initially (and update in the background).

Should I be doing this? Is there any problem with saving everything in core data (for a better user experience), or are there any limitations or problems that might occur when the data set grows larger? Are there some good practices that I must follow in terms of what to save and what not to save persistently?

Thanks

Comment: you can save everyhıng to Core data but problem arıses when the data groes and you want to fetch them.If you do not fetch all entries in the time line it should not matter.You can limit the fetch results (number of objects return) or limit with a predicate like time or something.

Comment: Fetching wont be a problem. I will only be fetching the required objects and not everything. But my question is is it good practice to save, for instance, a friend's feed objects, because it is low probability that I might visit that friends profile again and the save objects will be needed again. Or is there any downside on saving extra data? PS. Facebook app does not save a friends feed and fetches from the server each time we visit a friends profile

Comment: From software achitecture perspective you can cache certain data but mostly social network apps are thin client apps.It means all data is retrieved from the server on request.Your approach is not very common.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I know its not common ... but I'm looking for an answer as to "why". I would any day prefer something present in my views compared to showing an activity indicator while fetching data that I could've saved. And the data will be refreshed in the background anyways so there wont be a problem of the data getting stale

Comment: Like for instance would it be good practice to save just the recent 20 of the friend's feed objects ... so that whenever we "re-visit" any friend, we don't get to see that stinkin' activity indicator

Comment: yes that is what i  mean i assume you show for isntance only 20 latest feed if user taps on next you can additionally save the next 20 ans so on.But when user leaves the app i would clean the stored entries.Othwerwise you would also need to consider synchronization issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in principle you can use your approach in order to immediately show some data, there are some significant tradeoffs. On the whole, I think your approach is problematic.

Compare your situation with the Mail app on the iPhone (at least when you are using a mail server with some latency.) When you open a mailbox you will see old messages as well as a spinning wheel indicating that an update is running. Then, suddenly,  the display is updated with all your new messages. Your approach is very similar to this.

That might be OK for mail messages, but is it really acceptable for news feeds and status messages? I don't think so. Stale status messages (think "I'm feeling blue.") when the situation has already changed (think "I'm feeling great.") are misleading and will result in a dismal user experience.

Your Core Data store could still store all of the data and periodically wipe itself. The initial fetch could be such that items older than a certain threshold are not shown (and deleted). At the same time, it makes perfect sense to persist more permanent data (such as the friends list).